# Issue with Late binding in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am doing something of the sort:

```
return View("XXXXXX", new
        {
            Message = "ok"
        });
```

However when trying to read the variable via Model.Message an exception is thrown:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Message'

Even though hovering on `Model` in the debugger shows `Message = "ok"`

Any Idea why this might be happening ?

Comment: Could you show View codes?

Comment: Your problem might be because you're sending an anonymous type, which is getting translated into an object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559000/how-to-use-anonymous-list-as-model-in-an-asp-net-mvc-partial-view

Comment: You would have to specify dynamic as the model type; however, I had issues with that and resorted to using a strongly-typed model.

Comment: @IronMan84 and AliRıza Adıyahşi well yes thought so ... so the answer is "don't use anonymous types as Models" ? I find it odd especially since the debugger can see the variable and its value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, the trouble you're running into is that you're trying to use an anonymous type to pass through to the view. This means it will show up in your debugger, but your page will blow up, since it will interpret it as an `object` and not the type you're trying for.

The best solution for it would be to create a new Model class that has the Message property in it and to strongly type your View to that Model.