# ASP.NET MVC 5 Form Validation and Error Handling

Tags: asp.net, forms, validation, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5

Trying to implement data validation and error handling on a simple contact form. When I add the check for `ModelState.IsValid` I'm in a chicken and egg situation. I have looked at other similar questions and am just not getting this. Moving from Web Forms to MVC and struggling. Trying to toggle HTML elements based on what's happening - success/error message, etc. RIght now, not even the validation is working.

Right now I'm just trying to get server-side validation working but would welcome advice on how to add client-side validation also; for example, is it necessary to use jQuery for this or is there something baked in?

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    if (ViewData["Error"] == null && ViewData["Success"] == null)
    {
        <h3>Send us an email</h3>
        Html.ValidationSummary(true);
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="contact-email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email..."   
                class="contact-email" id="contact-email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="contact-subject">Subject</label>
            <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject..."
                class="contact-subject" id="contact-subject">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
             <label class="sr-only" for="contact-message">Message</label>
             <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message..." 
                 class="contact-message" id="contact-message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Send it</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
    }   
    else if (ViewData["Error"] == null && ViewData["Success"] != null)
    {
        <h4>We will get back to you as soon as possible!</h4>
        <p>
            Thank you for getting in touch with us. If you do not hear 
            from us within 24 hours, that means we couldn't contact you 
           at the email provided. In that case, please feel free to call 
           us at (xxx) xxx-xxxx at any time.
        </p>
    }
    else if (ViewData["Error"] != null)
    {
        <h3>Oops!</h3>
        <p>
            We apologize. We seem to be having some problems.
        </p>
        <p>
            Please come back and try again later. Alternatively, 
            call us anytime at (xxx) xxx-xxxx.
        </p>
    } 
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class ContactModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email address is required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Subject is required")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Message is required")]
    public string Message  { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult Contact(ContactModel contactModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.mydomain.com"))
            {
                // Standard mail code here

                ViewData["Success"] = "Success";
             }
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
             ViewData["Error"] 
                 = "Something went wrong - please try again later.";
                    return View("Error");
         }
     }
     return View();
}
```

**Error View:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <hgroup>
        <h1>Error.</h1>
        <h2>An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
    </hgroup>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE - 05/09/2017**

Per Guruprasad's answer, if `ModelState.IsValid` evaluates to false, then no validation error messages are being reported on the form.

**Note** I had to change the `AddModelError` signature to not use the "Extension ex" parameter:`ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Server side error occurred");` as I do not want system errors being reported to users.

**Note also** that at this point I am only trying out validation on the server side (have yet to work through client-side validation).
I have updated the Contact.cshtml view as follows as no model errors were being displayed - I have included the Bootstrap `.has-error` and `.help-block` CSS rules for the validation errors:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <h3>Send us an email</h3>
    Html.ValidationSummary(true);
    <div class="form-group has-error">
        <label class="sr-only" for="contact-email">Email</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { type = "text", name = "email",
            placeholder = "Email..", @class = "contact-email" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, String.Empty, 
            new { @class="help-block" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-error">
        <label class="sr-only" for="contact-subject">Subject</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Subject, new { type = "text", 
            name = "subject", 
            placeholder = "Subject..", @class = "contact-subject" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject, String.Empty, 
            new { @class = "help-block" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-error">
        <label class="sr-only" for="contact-message">Message</label>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { name = "message", 
            placeholder = "Message..", @class = "contact-message" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message, String.Empty, 
            new { @class = "help-block" })
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Send it</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset</button>

    if (ViewData["Success"] != null)
    {
        <h4>We will get back to you as soon as possible!</h4>
        <p>
            Thank you for getting in touch with us. If you do not hear 
            from us within 24 hours, that means we couldn't contact you 
            at the email provided. In that case, please feel free to 
            call us at (xxx) xxx-xxxx at any time.
        </p>
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the jquery validation scripts?

Comment: Yes, as part of the project template. It's version 1.11.1 - should I update?

Comment: Did you debug n see what error was existing when you had `ModelState.IsValid` as false? Also, if you do not want system errors to be reported to user, then you can configure that in web.config files where you can have your own custom views for different error codes.. Also on the other hand, Please look at `ExceptionFilter` which you can extend to display different custom views for different error types.. Let me know if you face any issues on this..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I got the model errors to show after adding the @Html.ValidationMessageFor's.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple things you need to understand here. Let me go point by point.

- Its good to know that you have your `model` designed, but how your view gets to know that it has a `model` to bind for itself and when posting the `form` contents, how would `server` comes to know that, there is a `model` to be received. So on the first instance, you need to construct your view binding the `model`. To bind a `model` in a `view`, you need to first get a reference/declare it at the top, letting view know that, ok, here is a `model` for you to generate my `view`.
- Well, you have `ValidationSummary` to `true`, then I would suggest that, instead of using `ViewData` to pass error message, you can use `ModelState.AddModelError` and let `ValidationSummary` take care of that. As a side note, you might also want to take care of **[this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107263/why-is-validationsummarytrue-displaying-an-empty-summary-for-property-errors)** and you can resolve the same with answers mentioned in the same post. If you are not using or do not want to use `Html.ValidationSummary`, then you can stick to your current view.
- Now, to display `Success` message, you can either use `TempData` or `ViewData` and follow the same structure as you have in your view now. Here is **[one more post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13550295/2065039)** to let you work on that.
- Last and most important on `View` part is binding `model` properties to `View` elements. Use `Razor View` extension helpers to generate `View` for your `model`. You have `@Html.TextBoxFor`,`@Html.TextAreaFor` etc., You also have `@Html.TextBox`, `@Html.TextArea` which is not for binding `model properties`, but just to generate a plain `HTML view`. You can add other `html` properties within these `helpers` as shown in the updated `view` below. I would suggest to dig down more on the overloads available for these helpers.

So here is your updated view.

```
@model SOTestApplication.Models.ContactModel   @*getting model reference*@

@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <h3>Send us an email</h3>
    Html.ValidationSummary(true);
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="contact-email">Email</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { type = "text", name = "email", placeholder = "Email..", @class = "contact-email" })
        @*Usage of helpers and html attributes*@
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="contact-subject">Subject</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Subject, new { type = "text", name = "subject", placeholder = "Subject..", @class = "contact-subject" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="contact-message">Message</label>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { name = "message", placeholder = "Message..", @class = "contact-message" })
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Send it</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
}
if (ViewData["Success"] != null)
{
    <h4>We will get back to you as soon as possible!</h4>
    <p>
        Thank you for getting in touch with us. If you do not hear
        from us within 24 hours, that means we couldn't contact you
        at the email provided. In that case, please feel free to call
        us at (xxx) xxx-xxxx at any time.
    </p>
}
```

**Controller Side validation**

Not much to say on this part as it looks good. But based on few of my points above, I would suggest you to add `ModelState.AddModelError` instead of using `ViewData` for error messages. Eliminate your `if` conditions in view, so that **contact form** remains, even after `postback`. Now if you want to persist the values after `server side` validation, then just pass back the `model` to your `view` in your `post` method. Updated `Controller` would be:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact(ContactModel contactModel)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          try
          {
              MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
              using (var smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.mydomain.com"))
              {
                  // Standard mail code here
                  ViewData["Success"] = "Success";
              }
          }
          catch (Exception)
          {
              ModelState.AddModelError("Server side error occurred", ex.Message.ToString());
          }
     }
     return View(contactModel); //this will persist user entered data on validation failure
}
```

**Client Side Validation**

As far as this portion is considered, you have few more things to set up in your application.

- You need to add `Html.EnableClientValidation(true);` and `Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript(true);` to your application. There are various possible ways to add this. You can add this on `Web.config` file under `appSettings` for global implication Or you can add this in particular `view` as mentioned in below updated `View` example.

**Global Implication in Web.Config ex:**

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

- If you have noticed your `BundleConfig.cs` file under **App_Start** directory, you would have seen below entries created by default. These are the `jquery` stuffs responsible for your **Client Side validation.**

**`jQuery` and `jQueryVal` entries**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

- Next Step is to add reference to these files/use `@section Scripts` to render these `bundles` either in `_Layout.cshtml` or in any specific `view`. When you include this in `_Layout.cshtml`. these scripts/bundles are rendered wherever you use this `layout` with other views. So basically, its your call on where to render these.

For example here, I would render these in `Contact.cshtml view` soon after adding reference to `model`.

```
@section Scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

- One Last thing to make this work here is that you need to use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` razor extension and let `MVC` do the binding of error messages on particular properties. Also for these error messages to be displayed in the `View`, **you need to specify `ErrorMessage` for each property in your `model`** as you are doing it now with `Required(ErrorMessage=...` for each properties in `model`. There are more to know about these stuffs if you explore it in detail.

Your updated view with proper validations added.

```
@model SOTestApplication.Models.ContactModel
@section Scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Contacts", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <h3>Send us an email</h3>
    Html.ValidationSummary(true);
    Html.EnableClientValidation(true);
    Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript(true);
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="contact-email">Email</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { type = "text", name = "email", placeholder = "Email..", @class = "contact-email" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="contact-subject">Subject</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Subject, new { type = "text", name = "subject", placeholder = "Subject..", @class = "contact-subject" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Subject)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="contact-message">Message</label>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { name = "message", placeholder = "Message..", @class = "contact-message" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Send it</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
    if (ViewData["Success"] != null)
    {
        <h4>We will get back to you as soon as possible!</h4>
        <p>
            Thank you for getting in touch with us. If you do not hear
            from us within 24 hours, that means we couldn't contact you
            at the email provided. In that case, please feel free to call
            us at (xxx) xxx-xxxx at any time.
        </p>
    }
}
```

Hope I have clarified most of your doubts with these points. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: Very, very thorough answer. Thanks so much for the effort. Will attempt this later today :)

Comment: @IrishChieftain Sure please.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: Hi Guruprasad, I had to update the question as your solution wasn't working for me - still working on server-side only.

Comment: I got the success message rendering but the form fields (populated) are still appearing on post back, above the success message? I took the if(ViewDate[]) code block out of the using block (per your example) and pre-pended it with "@". I'm still getting the populated form fields rendering with the success message on post back...

Comment: Just `null` the respective model buddy or just initialize with `new model()` once it is `success`.. As in, after `ViewData["Success"] = "Success";` just add `contactModel=new ContactModel()`.. that's it..

Comment: That had no effect, but I got it working by putting an if/else around the entire using{} block in the View. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Anytime buddy.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: This reply was useful, but still I have a problem when the fields in the form are dinamyc, or let´s say, if some fields are part of a partial view, and others are inside the form. Even If I don't want to validate partial view, the form submits instead of validating (but I can see validation messages though)