# Partial view with RenderPartial, model does not contain a definition

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a controller which returns a view.

Within the view I render a common shared partial view, and pass parameters in to it:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab-sla">@{Html.RenderPartial(
        "./_sla",
        new
        {
            ContentTitle = "Service Level"
        });
    }
</div>
```

However whenever in the partial view `_sla` I try and access the property ContentTitle, it throws an error `'object' does not contain a definition for 'ContentTitle'`.

If i dump the model properties with `@Model.ToString()` it shows `{ ContentTitle = "Service Level" }`.

Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong and how this can be fixed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC Razor dynamic model, 'object' does not contain definition for 'PropertyName'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862122/mvc-razor-dynamic-model-object-does-not-contain-definition-for-propertyname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help (taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4902229/562183) SO answer, thanks to Lucas):

> According to David Ebbo, you can't pass an anonymous type into a
>   dynamically-typed view because the anonymous types are compiled as
>   internal. Since the CSHTML view is compiled into a separate assembly,
>   it can't access the anonymous type's properties.

You may also try using `ViewData` when accessing model properties. Helps me sometimes:

```
<h1>@ViewData["ContentTitle"]</h1>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @JohnH Yes, because I had some additional information (which might be useful) to share.

Comment: @JohnH and that's why I'd prefer this question to be closed ;-) The workaround that I mentioned might be enough, though, thus the answer (I don't know whether the author wants to go for a normal model type).

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now, weirdest thing is i am doing the same from within a partial view that calls another partial view and that works OK. I will create a model before using it, or just use `@model string` and pass in a string (a workaround i just did)

Comment: @g18c, see my answer in the linked question for full details on the anomaly you are experiencing. It's a real gotcha!

Comment: The view and the partial views are on the same assembly.

Answer (score 0):

For full details please see the question and my answer here:

[MVC Razor dynamic model, 'object' does not contain definition for 'PropertyName'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862122/mvc-razor-dynamic-model-object-does-not-contain-definition-for-propertyname/21633464#21633464)

Essentially, the most likely reason it stopped working is because you *have another view in the same folder with a model type that is not resolvable*.

Correct the offending view with the broken model type, clean and rebuild the solution and it should work again.