# Asp.Net MVC 4 Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello friend I have a problem in mvc 4 to send a dynamic model in View suggest me how to bind dynamic model with the view

Here is my Action

```
[ChildActionOnly]

    public ActionResult TopArticles()
    {
        var model = from a in db.Articles.Take(3).OrderBy(m=>m.TotalViews) 
                    join u in db.UserProfiles 
                        on a.CreatedBy equals u.ID 
                    join t in db.Tags 
                        on a.TagID equals t.ID 
                    select new 
                    { 
                        Title = a.Title,
                       ArticleID = a.ArticleID, 
                        FirstName = u.FirstName, 
                        CreatedBy = a.CreatedBy, 
                        TagID = a.TagID, 
                        TagName = t.Name, 
                        CreationDate = a.CreationDate, 
                        TotalViews = a.TotalViews 
                    };  // get Top 3 Articles from Articles
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

And Here is my View

```
 @model IEnumerable<dynamic>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TopArticles";   
}
@foreach(dynamic item in Model)
{
   <div class="row about_topviewedarticle1">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="columns twenty">
     <a href="#" class="title">@item.Title</a>
by   <a href="#"class="profilefont_eleven">@item.FirstName</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="columns twenty">
                        <label class="font_ten">views: @item.TotalViews  posted on : @item.CreationDate</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            }
```

When I run this code following error is showing

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Title'

Comment: You have to make a view model, e.g. ArticlesViewModel, which will contains this parts of Articles entity which you want to show. After that in the query you will have ...select new ArticlesViewModel { ... }. Finally pass the view model to the view.

Answer (score 2):

### 1st way

**try this**

```
var model = from a in db.Articles.Take(3).OrderBy(m=>m.TotalViews) 
                    join u in db.UserProfiles 
                        on a.CreatedBy equals u.ID 
                    join t in db.Tags 
                        on a.TagID equals t.ID 
                    **select new Article**
                    { 
                        Title = a.Title,
                       ArticleID = a.ArticleID, 
                        FirstName = u.FirstName, 
                        CreatedBy = a.CreatedBy, 
                        TagID = a.TagID, 
                        TagName = t.Name, 
                        CreationDate = a.CreationDate, 
                        TotalViews = a.TotalViews 
                    };
```

> According to [David Ebbo](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/12/18/passing-anonymous-objects-to-mvc-views-and-accessing-them-using-dynamic.aspx), you can't pass an anonymous type into a dynamically-typed view because the anonymous types are compiled as internal. Since the CSHTML view is compiled into a separate assembly, it can't access the anonymous type's properties.

[See this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862122/mvc-razor-dynamic-model-object-does-not-contain-definition-for-propertyname)

**or,**

### 2nd Way

**converting the anonymous object into an ExpandoObject right away.**

```
public static ExpandoObject ToExpando(this object anonymousObject)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> anonymousDictionary =  new RouteValueDictionary(anonymousObject);
    IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
    foreach (var item in anonymousDictionary)
        expando.Add(item);
    return (ExpandoObject)expando;
}



 var model = from a in db.Articles.Take(3).OrderBy(m=>m.TotalViews) 
                        join u in db.UserProfiles 
                            on a.CreatedBy equals u.ID 
                        join t in db.Tags 
                            on a.TagID equals t.ID 
                      select new 
                        { 
                            Title = a.Title,
                           ArticleID = a.ArticleID, 
                            FirstName = u.FirstName, 
                            CreatedBy = a.CreatedBy, 
                            TagID = a.TagID, 
                            TagName = t.Name, 
                            CreationDate = a.CreationDate, 
                            TotalViews = a.TotalViews 
                        }**.ToExpando()**;
```

referred from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120317/dynamic-anonymous-type-in-razor-causes-runtimebinderexception)  and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121472/An-introduction-to-Expando-Object-Dotnet-4-0)