# how do i select from multiple table and return the result to the view mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

i am trying to display the result from this query in my index view, but it is reporting error, i have tried to debug it, no success, i will appreciate if anyone could assist in letting me know where i have gone wrong.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {           
       var users =
        (from u in db.Users
                     join s in db.States
                         on u.StateId
                         equals s.StateId

                     join l in db.Lgas
                         on u.LgaId
                         equals l.LgaId
                     select new
                     {
                         u.Surname,
                         u.Firstname,
                         u.Othernames,
                         u.Email,
                         s.StateName,
                         l.LgaName
                     }).ToList();


        return View(users);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant pass anonymous object to View because every property of anonymous object marked `internal` and Views are in a different namespace. [Here is great explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21633464/1849444).

Use ViewModel - it's the best solution.

ViewModel example:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
   public string Surname { get; set; }
   public string Firstname { get; set; }
   public string Othernames { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string StateName { get; set; }
   public string LgaName { get; set; }
}
```

Your Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{           
   var users =
    (from u in db.Users
                 join s in db.States
                     on u.StateId
                     equals s.StateId

                 join l in db.Lgas
                     on u.LgaId
                     equals l.LgaId
                 select new UserViewModel
                 {
                    Surname =  u.Surname,
                    Firstname = u.Firstname,
                    Othernames = u.Othernames,
                    Email = u.Email,
                    StateName = s.StateName,
                    LgaName = l.LgaName
                 }).ToList();


    return View(users);
}
```

And at the begin of your View:

```
@model List<YourViewModelNamespase.UserViewModel>
```

Change `YourViewModelNamespase` to actual namespace of your `UserViewModel` class.

On your View, you can do with your data anything you want everything in `Model` property.

Comment: the statename and lga name are not in the same table, with other property, i am selecting fro three different tables, and also how do i use the Viewmodel in the controller?

Comment: @UwakMfon What's wrong that they are in different tables? You already join them with your linq statement. I already write your controller for you. check `select new UserViewModel` that's where you use ViewModel. You just create instanses of `UserViewModel` not anonymouse type.

Comment: Thanks, but this line is reporting error: @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Surname)

Comment: @UwakMfon note that you have `List` of objects and i see you try to access properties like it's only one object.

Comment: It works, Thanks. But i had to change @modelList<YourViewModelNamespase.UserViewModel> to @model IEnumerable<YourViewModelNamespase.UserViewModel>